# How do you open a file line by line in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, iphone, file-io, cordova, streamreader

I'm looking to do some pretty data-intensive stuff using phonegap. The first thing I looked at was to stream-read a JSON file line by line to collect the data needed. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way. Is there a memory-effective way of stream-reading a file from phonegap?

John.

Comment: you mean a local json file from the devivce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is currently not possible with the standard phonegap api.

Files are written completely into a DOMString right now.

If you really need this you can take a look into writing a phonegap plugin that returns files by line. Here the link to the wiki to get you starting writing plugins: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap-Plugins

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I feared this was the case. We need to look into whether there are any other options, but it looks like this could well be what we end up doing :)